# Create / Destroy EC2 instances for ECS tasks

Tags: autoscaling, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have various Fargate tasks. They work fine. I then have a few additional tasks that require more disc space than silly old Fargate will allow. These have to run on EC2 instances that I have assigned to their respective cluster.

I trigger these tasks using cloudwatch events.

Because I have so few of these EC2 powered tasks, it seems silly having these EC2 instances sitting around.

My thought was to create / destroy the EC2 instances on demand, probably by using Lambda.

My proposed sequence:

- Cloudwatch Start event
- Lambda auto scales the EC2 instances for the ECS cluster to 1
- EC2 Cloudwatch ready event
- ECS task is started
- ECS task finishes and triggers a Cloudwatch event
- Lambda down scales the cluster

Is this feasible? Is there a pattern or better way to do this? Perhaps the Lambda function is unnecessary if there's a way to trigger the autoscale straight from the cloudwatch event?

Please note that these tasks are *not* scheduled, so it's not a matter of scheduling the autoscaling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AWS Batch. It is a service specifically designed for your situation, and can be triggered by CloudWatch Events

Comment: Thank you. This is what I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine.  You could also have the ECS service desired capacity raised at the same time as the EC2 ASG desired capacity is to remove a step, unless you're launching standalone tasks.  The ECS service will just keep trying to launch the task until the instance gets registered to the cluster.

How do you know when a task/instance need to be started, what's the trigger for that?  Whatever it is, you could use it to directly trigger the Lambada function.  Or if its a CloudWatch metric, then skip the CW Event and Lambda function and have a CW alarm directly increase the ASG and ECS desired capacity (or example, if the initiating factor is something in an SQS queue)